# What is the analogue of the "-fno-elide-constructors" for MinGW?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mingw, compiler-optimization

I'm currently studying lvalue, rvalue, move semantics and perfect forwarding. For a better understanding, I want to turn off all optimizations, but compiler of the Visual Studio 2017 do not provide this feature. Parameter `/Od` is available, but it do not turn off `nrvo`, `rvo` and other "reference" optimizations. I was lucky to find the parameter `-fno-elide-constructors` but it is works only for GCC and not for MinGW-W64 8.1.0

**Questions:**

1. What is the analogue of the "-fno-elide-constructors" for MinGW?
2. If MinGW does not provide this feature, Then which should i use the compiler on Windows?
3. Maybe there is academic compiler exists, who does not perform any optimizations and intended for studying only?

Comment: MinGW *is* GCC. On my MinGW GCC 9.2 (installed from MSYS2) the flag is there.

Comment: Note, the compiler is required to [always perform copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Mandatory_elision_of_copy.2Fmove_operations) in certain scenarios by C++ 17 standard, i.e. it is treated not as a possible optimization but as a language feature.

Comment: It would improve the question to post a complete program that you think is not being processed correctly by the compiler